# asp.net website built in Visual Studio Express 2015 for web open in VS2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I have a web project (asp.net website) built in VSExpress 2015 für Web.
Now I want to switch to VS2019 (Community). I installed everything. Opening the website project with the VS version selector (normal way) tries to open the web project with VS for Desktop. I didn't find any way to open this project in VS 2019 community. Does anyone know how to handle this?

This is the content of the .sln-file (if that does help in any way)

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio Express 14 for Web
VisualStudioVersion = 14.0.23107.0
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}") = "gute-regale.de", "gute-regale.de\", "{66CD3DE1-6751-4A93-837B-F6F2A510FFDC}"
    ProjectSection(WebsiteProperties) = preProject
        TargetFrameworkMoniker = ".NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.0"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/gute-regale.de"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "gute-regale.de\"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\gute-regale.de\"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "True"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/gute-regale.de"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "gute-regale.de\"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\gute-regale.de\"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "False"
        VWDPort = "52608"
        VWDDynamicPort = "false"
        VWDVirtualPath = "/"
        SlnRelativePath = "gute-regale.de\"
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {66CD3DE1-6751-4A93-837B-F6F2A510FFDC}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {66CD3DE1-6751-4A93-837B-F6F2A510FFDC}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Comment: any error message? you didnt get the upgrade request from visual studio to upgrade the solution?

Comment: VS version selector tries to open the project with VS desktop developement tool. The only error message is that VS can't open this project with the VS desktop developement tool. That is of course correct. The VS version selector should recognize that the project isn't a desktop application and should open it with the correct developement tool but it doesn't.

Comment: is the "development tool" installed on the new VS? i think you can install modules from the help in the main menu.